# Custom UITableViewCell Not Loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am creating my own custom UITableViewCell using interface builder. I am supporting iOS 5 & iOS 6 but I do not want to use Storyboard. Please do not suggest storyboard. I'm sticking to Interface Builder and writing programatically.

I created a class that subclasses UITableViewCell. Here's the .h file:

```
@interface CategoryCell : UITableViewCell
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *name;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *distance;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *number;
    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *rating;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *distance;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *number;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *rating;

@end
```

The XIB file is of type UIViewController and has a View of type CategoryCell. I connected the outlets as I have to.

**The Problem**

`dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier` is not calling the custom cell. Here's what I have:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CategoryCell";
        CategoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
            .....
        }
        return cell
}
```

When I substitute the `loadBundle` line with: `cell = [[CategoryCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];`, it does work. But the nib does not load. So a cell loads, but not my own cell so I cannot set the labels and images that I want. When adding the regular load bundle line (as the sample above shows) and breakpoint the `init` method of the custom cell, it does not get called. Also, what I get is a full white screen that overrides the whole iPhone screen in the simulator.

Why's that happening? What am I doing wrong here? When I tried setting the outlets to `strong` (which I know I'm not supposed to), it does not work either.

**EDIT**:

I fixed it by replacing the NSBundle line with:

```
UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryCell" bundle:nil];
cell = (CategoryCell *)temporaryController.view;
```

What is it that I've done wrong with the NSBundle method? Supposedly that's supposed to be the "easier" way to do it.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint and looked at the value of topLevelObjects and thence cell?  That would be useful information, to see if they are nil or not.

Answer (score 6):

Have you ever try the registerNib method in tableview? It's very convenient for load nib start from iOS 5.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CategoryCell" bundle:nil]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryCell"];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CategoryCell";
    CategoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    return cell
}
```

make sure you have define identifier in the CategoryCell.nib , it's under Attribute inspector! Hope this work.

Comment: have you checked the class in the nib is point to CategoryCell? not the file's owner but the cell under Objects in nib.

Comment: Yes I did , it is of type CategoryCell

Comment: And the file owner of this xib should be NSObject instead of the UIViewController, since you don't need to attach the nib to controller if you implement in this way.

Answer (score 0):

> The XIB file is of type UIViewController and has a View of type CategoryCell. I connected the outlets as I have to.

The problem in this is that the root object of your XIB need to be a UITableViewCell or a subclass of it.
And be sure to have your reuse identifier set in your XIB.

Comment: It is of type CategoryCell. File's Owner is UIViewController but the View is of type CategoryCell, which is a subclass of UITableViewCell. I've also set the reuse identifier.